# Wild card, adding to a list throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, generics

```
public static void wildCard2(List<? super Base> lst){
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        System.out.println(lst.get(i));
    }
    lst.add(new Base());

}
```

As shown in the  code above, I have a class called Base. 
Can anyone explain why this fails at RunTime and throws `UnsupportedOperationException` ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Hi, can you please post which error you're getting?

Comment: Which List implementation do you use?

Comment: @Nikunj - he posted error in subject - `UnsupportedOperationException` while adding element to list.

Comment: you need to show your calling part too specifically which `List` is getting passed for `lst`

Answer (score 1):

The [`add(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) method defined on the `List<E>` interface is specified as an *optional* operation.

If you're getting an `UnsupportedOperationException` at runtime, this means that the `List` implementation that you're using does *not* support this operation.

It might be an unmodifiable type created by calling [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-), an instance of a Guava [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html), or something else entirely. Check the runtime type to find out:

```
System.out.println(lst.getClass().getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `.add()` from such a `List`, you can create a copy of the list to a known-modifiable implementation like `ArrayList`.